# Check if url parameter is a number

Tags: elixir

I am exploring the world of Elixir and build the following:

```
defmodule Hello do
  def init(default_opts) do
    IO.puts "starting up App..."
    default_opts
  end

def call(conn, _opts) do
  route(conn.method, conn.path_info, conn)
end

def route("GET", ["customers", cust_id], conn) do
   # check parameter
   IO.puts user_id
   IO.puts "Check if user_id is a number:"
   IO.puts is_number(cust_id)

  if is_number(cust_id) do
    conn |> Plug.Conn.send_resp(200, "Customer id: #{cust_id}")
    else 
     conn |> Plug.Conn.send_resp(404, "Couldn't find customer, sorry!")
  end

end
```

I am wondering why the `is_number` function (or `is_integer`) is giving false as result. The url I am using is: `http://localhost:4000/customers/12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_number(cust_id)` is false because `cust_id`  is a string containing integer digits, but it's not actually a number. It *can* be parsed into an integer but it's a string because `conn.path_info` does not automatically convert integer-looking strings into integers. You can check if a string is a valid integer using [`Integer.parse/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2):

```
if match?({_, ""}, Integer.parse(cust_id)) do
  conn |> Plug.Conn.send_resp(200, "Customer id: #{cust_id}")
else 
  conn |> Plug.Conn.send_resp(404, "Couldn't find customer, sorry!")
end
```